# If I remove the MsgBox the Code fails to run, How is that possible and how to fix it?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a code that uses WPF Interoperability where I have WPF Item that is being added as user control in windows forms. I use the WPF for 3D view where I add a sphere dynamically and it works fine, all I do is just send x, y and radius from the form to WPF and it draws the sphere.
Now here it is the problem I made a loop that reads list of coords and draws them in WPF control, it works perfectly if I add a blank MsgBox but if I remove the MsgBox it only shows the last sphere in the list, Eg

```
   For Each obj As Sphere in LstSpheres

        MsgBox("") 'If I remove this the code doesn't work
        CreateSphere(obj.x, obj.y, obj.radius, Brushes.Red) 'This Sub adds the Sphere in WPF Control

    Next
```

How is that possible, and how can it be fixed?

UPDATE:

```
CreateSphere

        Dim S As New Sphere ' a ready made object I took and it doesn't use threaing
        S.Radius = Radius
        S.X = x
        S.Y = y
        S.BrushColor = Color
        My3DViewport3D.Children.Add(S)
```

Comment: What does the `CreateSphere` method look like?

Comment: So, what«s going on in CreateSphere? Threading perhaps? Clear the screen?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes I'm notusing any threading, I will add the code

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk Ok I will add the code

Comment: Does My3DViewport3D.Children contain all the spheres when you don't show a msgbox?

Comment: @JKJKJK yes it contains all the spheres with or with out MsgBox.

Comment: @Kronass Change the for each to a for loop and show the message box after a couple iterations. Whats the result?

Comment: @JKJKJK the time that only MsgBox showed the spheres were visible and the times where MsgBox didn't showed up the spheres where not visible in the same iteration. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious what happens if you do something like this.

```
Dim temp As String = ""

For Each obj As Sphere in LstSpheres
    CreateSphere(obj.x, obj.y, obj.radius, Brushes.Red)
    temp &= "[" & My3DViewport3D.Children.Count & "]"
Next

MsgBox(temp)
```

Comment: The number of inserted spheres are displayed

Comment: Any how I have solved the problem by putting the create sphere function in a Timer that executes every 5 milliseconds, I tried threading but it didn't work. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a threading issue?  Maybe the act of stopping the code for the message box allows enough time for the last CreateSphere to complete?